# WPML - Hook when language is switched (change user language)

Tags: plugins, functions, actions, language, plugin-wpml

I would like to change the logged in user's language (if someone is logged in) when they change the language in front-end.

I'm using the **WPML Multilingual CMS** plugin in my Wordpress website.

I've tried to add this code in my custom plugin:

```
add_action('wpml_language_has_switched', 'change_user_language_in_database');

function change_user_language_in_database()
{
  die("test function");
}
```

The problem is that this function is always triggered. Also when the language isn't switched.

The version of WPML Multilingual CMS plugin is **4.2.7.1**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try maybe using a filter? Haven't had many clients using this plugin. According to docs there is a wpml_setting that stores different settings as well as their values.
https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_setting/

Comment: @YaroslavIshanov, I don't understand what you mean. I'm trying to check if the language in front-end is changed.